# how to use reduce method on an array of object having mix data types?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add amount as total from my array of objects whose structure is like this.

```
const details = [{ name: "smith",age: 29, amount: 100},
                { name: "Aero",age: 24, amount: 180},
                ].
```

i tried doing like this.

```
const totalAmt =  ExpensesData.reduce((total, item)=> {
    return total + item.amount;
});
```

but, i am not able to achieve it. one more thing i observe is the type of total is of object. as it holds the previous value and i am iterating through array of object.
Also, is **reduce** really an efficient way to achieve it ? or shall we use some other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reduce` method accepts a <del>third</del> **second** argument that will be used as the initial value for your computation.
As we're looking to calculate a sum, then setting `0` as the initial value is a good choice.

```js
const details = [{
      name: "smith",
      age: 29,
      amount: 100
    },
    {
      name: "Aero",
      age: 24,
      amount: 180
    },
  ],
  /**
   * a: is the returned value from the last iteration, initially starts with an empty object "{}".
   * c: is the current VALUE from "details" array.
   */
  totalAmount = details.reduce((a, c) => a + c.amount, 0);

// prints "totalAmount" value
console.log(totalAmount); // prints: 280
```

> Learn more about [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const details = [{ name: "smith",age: 29, amount: 100},
            { name: "Aero",age: 24, amount: 180},
            ]

const totalAmt =  details.reduce((total, item)=> {
    return total + item.amount;
},0);
```

Edited.

Comment: wrong answer.  it can only work with arrays of length ==2

Comment: it's good to have corrected, but why give a wrong answer the first time?

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution is

```
const totalAmount = details.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.amount + b.amount; // previous + current
});
```